# Transform yield in list

Tags: python, list, function, yield

I have this code:

```
def sumto(n, lst):
    if not n and not lst:  # base case 1: empty list = 0
        yield []
        return
    if n < 0 or not lst:  # base case 2: unsolvable
        return
    head, *tail = lst
    for sol in sumto(n-head, tail):  # recursion 1: use first element
        yield [head] + sol
    yield from sumto(n, tail)  # recursion 2: don't use first element
```

And I would like transform yield into a list.  How I can do it ?
So I just want don't use yield  but for example  `my_list.append`

Comment: Please don't drastically change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: Yes I know but I just needed about yield

Answer (score 4):

This is the equivalent:

```
def sumto(n, lst):
    result = []
    if not n and not lst:
        result.append([])
        return result
    if n < 0 or not lst:
        return result
    head, *tail = lst
    for sol in sumto(n-head, tail):
        result.append([head] + sol)
    result.extend(sumto(n, tail))
    return result
```

The following rules can be applied fairly generally to convert a generator function to one returning a `list`:

```
return
# =>
return result
# also think of an implicit "return" at the end of the generator function

yield x
# => 
result.append(x)

yield from x
# => 
result.extend(x)
```

Generally, however, you should strive to transform your code the other way round. Generators are one of Python's finest. They allow you to iterate all the elements without ever holding all of them in memory, they only do the generation work until you find what your looking for. And if you want a list, just call `list(...)` on them.